# Javascript if letter match including the Enter Key keycode 13

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I need to accept only letters and 0-9 digits, I also want to accept the Enter/Return key, but I don't know how to accept the Enter/Return key or keycode 13.

This is the code I am using:

```
if (letter.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/gi)){
    codes += letter;
}
```

Comment: `\n` or `\r\n` possibly?

Comment: Make your code print out what it receives. Press the Enter key. Write down what it says. Copy into code. (Mind that it may be a non-printing code.)

Comment: I know Enter keycode is 13, but I dont know where to put it in the code, that why I asked this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\r`.

```js
console.log(/^[a-z\d\r]+$/.test('\r')); // true
```

If you prefer character codes,

```js
console.log(/^[a-z\d\u000d]+$/.test('\r')); // true (0x0d == 13)
```